# Transform TXT to BIN, and print out the content of BIN

Tags: c, file, binary, fread, scanf

I'm trying to **transfrom a txt file to a binary file** , the txt includes **numbers** from 1-20 
divided by (enter) . As long as I know it works fine (debugged it ) but maybe it can include mistakes so you can see it. After that I wanna check what is is my binary file.
I want to **print the binary** file to monitor. However it prints one section of **memory dirt**.
*Could you help me find the **problem in my code?** thanks in advance*

```
void txt_to_bin (void)                                   /*Make binary from txt*/ 
{
    FILE *ft,*fb;
    int a;
    ft = fopen("binadatok.txt","rt");
    fb = fopen("versenyazonosito.dat","wb");
    while (fscanf(ft,"%d\n",&a) != EOF)
    {
        fwrite(&a,sizeof(a),1,fb);
        printf("%d\n", a);
    }
}

void bin_olvas(void)                       /*Print out the binary*/   
{
    FILE *f;
    int k;
    f = fopen("versenyazonosito.dat","rb");
    while(!feof(f))
    {
        (fscanf(f,"%d\n",&k) != EOF);  
        printf("%d\n", k);
    }
    fclose(f);
}
```

Comment: `(fscanf(f,"%d\n",&k) != EOF);` what is this supposed to do ?

Comment: I wanted to scan an int from f, and store it in k

Comment: But why did you enclose it in prentheses and put a semicolon after it `(abcd == 1234);` ? Given -Wall, GCC would probably complain: "statement has no meaning".

Comment: First I did not enclose it, but if I do that I get an erorr  " syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'printf'  "

Comment: Adding constructions at random until errors "go away" is [cargo cult programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming).

Answer (score 0):

`fscanf(f, "%d\n", &k)` is only useful for reading an ASCII file. You cannot use it for reading the binary data back from `versenyazonosito.dat`. You will have to use `fread` or something similar instead.

Comment: changed my read binary as you said to fread but it is still giving back memory dirt (  while(!feof(f))
 {

   (fread(&k,sizeof(k),1,f));  
  printf("%d\n", k);
  
 }